# Google Chrome issue with flash wmode: "transparent" cant catch click event

Tags: flash, events, google-chrome

It works on IE7 and mozilla, but on Chrome when u set param wmode: "transparent" it doesn't react to mouse event... Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below generates an **issue in Firefox**. To fix it, use:

```
<object data="yourMovie.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="740" height="103" id="menu" align="middle"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
        <param name="quality" value="best">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="movie" value="yourMovie.swf" />
        <embed src="" quality="high" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="740" height="103"></embed>
</object>
```

See you.

Comment: This does not seem to answer or fix the problem. Click events not getting through seems to be a chrome bug. Not sure this should be an accepted answer. Unless someone could explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the solution :

Try to use "mousedown" instead of "click" with jquery.

I did that: $('#yourobject').mousedown();

It works perfectly for me on chrome, ff, etc.

I also put my flash object in a div container. Don't know if it helps.

If you create your flash object via javascript (with swfobject.js), don't forget to use the ".live" method of jquery ( $('#yourobject').live('mousedown', function(){ ... });

Answer (score 0):

you can use html code like this:

```
 <object data="YourFile.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
        <param name="quality" value="best">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <embed src="" quality="high" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="550" height="400"></embed>
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="movie" value="YourFile.swf" />
    </object>
```