# Why do certain mouse events work in all browsers but Chrome?

Tags: flash, google-chrome, mouseevent, haxe

I have some code that gets fired on these mouse events:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(e:MouseEvent) { ...
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(e:MouseEvent) { ...
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, function(e:MouseEvent) { ...
```

They all work in all browsers, except for Chrome, where `MOUSE_OVER` and `MOUSE_OUT` trigger the events, but `MOUSE_UP` does not trigger the event. I also tried `CLICK`, same story.

I would suspect that there is some sort of interfering layer or offset in the Chrome rendering, but then wouldn't the other mouse events not register as well?

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are having issues due to the wmode being used when embedding the swf file. This answer already answers this question: [Google Chrome issue with flash wmode: "transparent" cant catch click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466977/google-chrome-issue-with-flash-wmode-transparent-cant-catch-click-event)